# Change text with a PHP function

Tags: php

I have a form containing a textarea.

When the users enters code like this:

```
chr(rand(97,122))
chr(rand(97,122))
chr(rand(98,122))
chr(rand(99,122))
```

The numbers in `rand()` can be any number - and validate the form.

I want to tranform this text into result of the php function `rand()` and `chr()`.

I try to use `eval()`, but didn't work for me.

Comment: what would you want the code to do if the user entered code like `readfile('/etc/passwd')`

Comment: Note that `chr(rand(97,122))chr(rand(97,122)chr(rand(98,122))chr(rand(99,122))` isn't valid PHP code, so perhaps that's why eval didn't work

Comment: I want to transform only rand and chr

Comment: I try to add "." between ) and chr but still show as a string

Comment: This is not a good idea at all, you open mile wide security gaps. So sit down, take a breath and first try to clearly define why and what you actually want to do.

Comment: _If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question._ -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Comment: If you really want use only `rand` and `chr`, put only numbers in textarea and the use it with appropriate functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead of evil(). Just match the numbers inside the function call and return the random characters, e.g.

```
$output = preg_replace_callback("/\s*chr\(rand\((\d+),(\d+)\)\)\s*/", function($m){
    return chr(rand($m[1], $m[2])); 
}, $input);

echo $output;
```